# Is it OK to inherit from an empty class?

Tags: java, oop, generics, design-patterns

I have an entity which has info1 or info2 dependently from its type, but only one of these infos should be filled. These infos have absolutely different properties. So my entity looks like this:

```
public class SomeEntity {

  private SomeEntityType type;

  private Info1 info1;  

  private Info2 info2;  

}
```

So my question is this Ok to create some empty abstract class Info and inherit Info1 and Info2 from it?
(Since I think that the number of such Info classes can grow and I will need add all such infos to SomeEntity)

```
public class Info1 extends Info {
  /* some properties */ 
}

public class Info2 extends Info {
  /* some properties */ 
}

public class SomeEntity {

  private SomeEntityType type;

  private Info info;   

}
```

Comment: Why not if it's technically possible? Especially, if you're going to implement their common behavior in the future.

Comment: @KonradRudolph it really depends and how fat an empty class is? The OP seems to need moving their `SomeEntityType type` right into the `Info` class (that would probably best `sealed` then in Java 15) and remove `SomeEntity`. Then they won't need an empty class at all.

Comment: Ok, your comment has gone.

Comment: @fluffy I misread the question. My comment didn’t apply here at all (in fact, if anything OP is *avoiding* the use of a fat interface here), hence removal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a word - yes, it is. However, it may be more idiomatic to use an empty **interface** and have `Info1` and `Info2` implement it rather than extend an empty class.

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course. That's why there is abstract class. You can create abstract class Info and write some abstract methods. You're going to implement those methods in classes Info1 and Info2.

Example

```
public abstract class Info {
    abstract void getInfo();
}

public class Info1 extends Info {

    void getInfo() {
        System.out.println("This is Info 1");

    }

}

public class Info2 extends Info {

    void getInfo() {
        System.out.println("This is Info 2");

    }

}
```

As you can see, I implemented methods differently in Info1 and Info2.

Comment: Your example doesn’t need an abstract base class, using an interface suffices.